# Convert + to %2B in a string PHP

Tags: php, ascii

So I have been debugging a script and a lot of the data being passed into it contained this symbol: '+'. I discovered that if I changed it to %2B that it worked. I know this must be sort of a very basic question but after poking around the PHP documentation, I couldn't find a solution. Is there a built-in PHP function for converting ascii symbols like this?

Comment: How and where is that data passed into it? Give an example.

Comment: The problem isn't how the data is getting passed, Im just trying to find the most efficient way to convert ascii symbols like this when I am working in PHP

Comment: Is there a reason this got voted down? I fixed the typo - was there something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it really `%2`? not `%2B`?

It looks like you're finding [`urlencode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).